# Class AVAssetDownloadTask is implemented in both CFNetwork and AVFoundation

Tags: xcode, avfoundation, watchos, urlsession, cfnetwork

When using Xcode 11.3 and running on watchOS 6.1.1, I see the following conflicts

```
objc[45250]: Class AVAssetDownloadTask is implemented in both /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/WatchOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/watchOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/Frameworks/CFNetwork.framework/CFNetwork (0x4ddd0ec) and /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/WatchOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/watchOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/Frameworks/AVFoundation.framework/AVFoundation (0x16aea494). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
objc[45250]: Class AVAssetDownloadURLSession is implemented in both /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/WatchOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/watchOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/Frameworks/CFNetwork.framework/CFNetwork (0x4dddd44) and /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/WatchOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/watchOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/Frameworks/AVFoundation.framework/AVFoundation (0x16aea4bc). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
```

Then my `URLSession` code stops working

```
2020-01-13 22:50:12.430920+0100 MyAppWatch WatchKit Extension[45250:2099229] Task <3CECDE81-59B9-4EDE-A4ED-1BA173646037>.<1> finished with error [-999] Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-999 "cancelled" UserInfo={NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://myapp.com/def.json, NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://myapp.com/def.json, NSLocalizedDescription=cancelled}
```

It works perfectly on watchOS 6.0 and before, this is probably due to URLSession classes conflicts. How to solve this?